# Creating Custom ID on update SQL Server (trigger?)

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server-2008, linq-to-sql, triggers

I have a table for requests and once they are approved/denied they need to be assigned a custom sequential ID like:

```
MYCODE-11-0001
MYCODE-11-0002
MYCODE-11-0003
```

where `MYCODE` doesn't change but `11` is the current year and `0001` is sequentially generated number assigned for the year. So each year it will start at 0001.

I've never dealt with triggers or stored procedures in SQL Sever so I had the idea of doing this in code via Linq-to-SQL in VB.net and I have another table in SQL Server that keeps track of the `Next ID`

```
ID     NAME          NextID
1      Request2011    102
2      Request2012    1
3      Request2013    1
```

If they changed the status on the website the app selects the name based on the current year and grabs the `NextID` and generates the `RequestID`. LINQ will even catch if `NextID` has changed since grabbing the value, adding one, and trying to save that new value.

Pretty sure this will work but not I'm exactly satisfied with this because it assumes everything will come from my app. I'd feel much better about this if it was done on the database level and even better if it didn't rely on this `NextID` table I had.

Is there anything with triggers and store procedures that wouldn't be too crazy that would allow me to generate these custom IDs? I have a vague idea that i could run a trigger when the `StatusID` is updated to run a stored procedure to do some of the heavy duty work(generated `RequestID` if not already set), but if I still have to rely on the `NextID` table then I have to worry about locking/unlocking the table as well correct?

Just hoping from some advice from people who know SQL Server far better than I do.

**Note:** The Custom ID is only assigned at time of approving/denying the request not when it was inserted into the database. Each request does have it own unique auto-generated identity PK.

---

**UPDATE:** I may have to stick with the code solution as it does all the hand holding for me as far as concurrency goes, but i did write up a trigger just so i could learn.

```
/* --------------------
        SETUP 
--------------------*/
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestData](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [data] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [RequestID] [varchar](25) NULL,
    [StatusID] [int] NULL
    )

    INSERT INTO TestData
           ([data],[StatusID])
     VALUES
           ('test',1)
GO


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[NextID](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](75) NULL,
    [NextID] [int] NULL,
    [DateModified] [date] NULL,
    [ModifiedBy] [varchar](75) NULL
    )
    INSERT INTO NextID
           ([Name],[NextID])          
     VALUES('RequestID2011',1)           
GO

/* --------------------
        TRIGGER
--------------------*/
IF EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sys.objects
      WHERE name = 'UpdateStatusID' AND type = 'TR')
   DROP TRIGGER dbo.UpdateStatusID;
GO

CREATE TRIGGER UpdateStatusID
ON dbo.TestData
AFTER UPDATE 
AS 
IF ( UPDATE (StatusID))
BEGIN
    DECLARE @nextId int
    DECLARE @nextIdName varchar(50)

    /* -- Get NextID based on year's count IE: RequestID2011 */
    SET @nextIdName = 'RequestID' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, YEAR(GetDate()), 50)
    SET @nextid = (Select NextID from dbo.NextID where Name = @nextIdName)

    /* -- Increment NextID */
    UPDATE dbo.NextID set NextID = @nextid + 1 WHERE Name=@nextIdName

    /* -- Set New RequestID */
    UPDATE dbo.TestData
    SET RequestID = 'MYCODE-' + RIGHT(@nextIdName,2) + '-' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, REPLICATE('0', (4- LEN(@nextid))) + @nextid, 50)
    FROM inserted i INNER JOIN dbo.TestData t
    ON i.id = t.id 

END;
GO
/* --------------------
        TEST
--------------------*/
UPDATE dbo.TestData
SET StatusID = 3
WHERE ID = 1;
GO
```

What this doesn't do is protect against someone changing the `StatusID` more than once (they can do that but i only need to generate the ID once) or protect against people grabbing `NextID` at the same time and having a race condition problem.

This also still requires me to have several records of 'RequestIDXXXX' in the database for future years.

**Warning:** This doesn't handle concurrency and is just a work in process on my path to understanding triggers and SQL Server.

Comment: Do you store a datetime value in the table too? And no more then 9999 rows per year?

Comment: I set a review date at the same time as the RequestID. Never say never but there shouldn't be more than 2000 requests a year.

Comment: Your trigger will only work for one inserted record. If you insert more than one record at once, they'll all end up with the same sequence ID. Also, you should increment your counter _before_ updating your data table.

Comment: If two updates happen wouldn't that cause two triggers to run and they'd both be matching the ID with the inserted table right? Updated increment location but this trigger has no many other things wrong with it which is why I'm not using it and did mentioned this doesn't handle concurrency at all. Perhaps this could help some one in the future on how to get started.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, having such a table for the next ID is a hotspot and often a bottleneck, too - if done correctly. If not, then you'll get duplicate ID's....

Right now, SQL Server 2008 R2 doesn't really have a good answer for you. This might change with SQL Server 2011 (or possibly: SQL Server 2012), codenamed "Denali". Denali will introduce **sequences**, which allow you to create sequential ID's under the database core's control, and those are guaranteed to be unique. You can also reset sequences back to 1 on Jan 1 of each new year.

Check out Aaron Bertrand's blog post on [SQL Server vNext (Denali): Using SEQUENCE](https://sqlblog.org/2010/11/11/sql-server-v-next-denali-using-sequence) for more information on sequences.

For now, yes, I guess your approach with either setting those ID's from your client-side using Linq-to-SQL, or inside a trigger, are probably the most suitable approaches (I would prefer the trigger solution, myself). I would think a single `INSTEAD OF INSERT` trigger on that table would suffice - if you insert a new row, get the new request ID you need and set it to the values you've just inserted.

Comment: It's looking like Denali might be SQL Server 2012 at this point.

Comment: Wow it hurts to see exactly what i need and can't use it. Thank you for sharing it though. BTW the custom ID is based on when the request has been approved/denied not when it is inserted into the database, but its nice to know something like INSTEAD OF INSERT exists too.

Comment: You could definitely modify my example above to have a different ID based on approved denied. You could use a PARTITION BY in the ROW_NUMBER() function to get what you needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can indeed do it with a trigger on your table, see below:

```
create table NextID (
    id  int,
    name    varchar(10),
    nextid  int
)

create table TestData (
    sequence    varchar(14) NOT NULL,
    data    varchar(10)
)

insert into NextID
values(1, 'Req2011', 1)


--Important stuff starts here
ALTER TRIGGER MySequence
ON TestData
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
DECLARE @nextid int

SET @nextid = (select nextid from NextID ) - 1

UPDATE NextID
SET nextid = nextid + (select COUNT(*) from inserted)
WHERE id = 1;

WITH cte AS (
    select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (select 1)) + @nextid as sequence, i.data
    from inserted i
)
insert into TestData
select 'MYCODE-' + RIGHT(YEAR(GETDATE()), 2) + '-' + RIGHT('000' + CAST(sequence as varchar), 4), data
from cte;
```

This is a pretty reliable way of doing it. Take note that the trigger is written to allow the insert of more than one record at a time.

Reference:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx

http://www.sqlmag.com/article/sql-server/nondeterministic-row-numbers

Comment: @James - That comment is definitely not correct. It will return the number of rows inserted by the `insert` statement.

Comment: @Martin: In cases where you're inserting a result set, right? In the case of his insert statement though, the Inserted table would only ever contain one row. Anyways, the point I was trying to make is that it can't be used for calculating the sequence.

Comment: Yes it can. That variable is used as a base, and then added to the result of the row_number function, therefore generating a sequence. Test it if you don't believe me.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
DECLARE @CustomID VARCHAR(255)
SELECT @CustomID = 'MYCODE-' + CAST((YEAR( GETDATE()) % 100) AS CHAR(2)) + '-' + REPLICATE('0', (4 - LEN((<Sequence> + 1)))) + CAST((<Sequence> + 1) AS VARCHAR(5))
```

EDIT

I don't know how you're looking to get the sequence, but if you're looking to pull it from a row count on the table, you can do something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(SomethingID) --Optionally add +1
FROM   SomethingTable
WHERE  DATEDIFF(YEAR, SomeDateColumn, GETDATE()) = 0
```

Comment: Not what i need since what I'm specifically asking for is how to generate the sequence ID not how to create a string based on a selected sequence id. But +1 since i did need REPLICATE

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that this not be the "id", in the primary key line of thought.

You could use a persisted computed column instead.  Something to the effect of:

```
ALTER TABLE myTable
ADD CustomID AS (

    'MYCODE-' + CAST(RIGHT(100 + year([date_field]),2) as varchar(2)) + CAST(RIGHT(10000 + [pk_field],4) as varchar(4))

) PERSISTED
```

This way, the work is done for you whenever a new record is added to the table.

The caution here is just that if you ever update the [pk_field] column (which is unlikely...?), your computed column will re-compute.  But otherwise, as long as you use 'PERSISTED', it will remain un-changed.

**EDIT**
I replaced `getdate()` with `[date_field]` above.  I still think a computed column is a good option for you, but the caveat is that you need a date field on the record (date_inserted, or what have you), as `getdate()` (or other non-deterministic values) cannot be used.

Comment: But GETDATE() is not constant, so the value would change each year. It should be based on another column. This assumes GETDATE is allowed in a computed column

Comment: @gbn -- OK -- you're right.  I just tested, and it won't even create the computed-column if you attempt to use a non-det value.  (error -- Computed column 'custom' in table 'tbl_cete' cannot be persisted because the column is non-deterministic).  I'll modify my answer.

Comment: I have a unique identity int PK for when the data is first interested into the database that i use for my app. This custom ID is for the reporting system and the format and numbering-by-year requirement is beyond my control. I can't give it the 'number' part until the request is officially approved/denied. Some prescreens take a lot longer than others.  If i didn't have to reset the number every year i'd just add MYCODE-REVIEWYEAR-PKID to a view column and be done with it.